# Subclass of QObject, qRegisterMetaType, and the private copy constructor

Tags: qt4

I have a class that is a subclass of QObject that I would like to register as a meta-type. The [QObject documentation](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/object.html#identity-vs-value)  states that the copy-constructor should be private, but the [QMetaType documentation](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType) states that a type should have a public default constructor, a **public copy constructor**, and a public destructor.

I can override QObject's private copy constructor and declare a public copy constructor, but is this safe/ok/right?

```
class MyClass : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(const MyClass &other);
    ~MyClass();
}
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass);
```

Comment: The way I ended up going is to use QSharedPointer (Qt 4.5 and up).

    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSharedPointer<MyClass>)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not safe to make a QObject's copy constructor public. You can register a class pointer as the metatype, though. i.e.:

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass*);

That's how Qt handles it with QObject and QWidget.

Answer (score 6):

What you're asking for is perfectly ok. You can't use `QObject`s copy constructor (it's private) in the implementation of your copy constructor, but then again, no-one forces you to:

```
class MyClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // ...
    MyClass( const MyClass & other )
        : QObject(), i( other.i ) {} // NOTE: calling QObject default ctor
    // ...
private:
    int i;
};
```

Depending on what services you need from `QObject`, you need to copy some properties over from `other`, in both the copy ctor and the copy assignment operator. E.g., if you use QObject for it's dynamic properties feature, you'd need to copy those, too:

```
    MyClass( const MyClass & other )
        : QObject(), i( other.i )
    {
        Q_FOREACH( const QByteArray & prop, other.dynamicPropertyNames() )
            setProperty( prop.constData(), other.property( prop.constData() ) );
    }
```

Likewise, if you want to maintain signal/slot connections.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So it's possible but needs to be very carefully coded.

Answer (score 0):

I use a separate `copyValue(const MyClass & other)` function to copy the data members that define the "values" of the `MyClass` instance. That ensures that I don't break the assumption of `QObject` unique identity, while still being able to duplicate the parts of the class that are defined at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

```
QTFruit fruit;
QScriptValue scriptedFruitObject = engine.newQObject(&fruit);
engine.globalObject().setProperty("fruit", scriptedFruitObject);

 engine.setDefaultPrototype(qMetaTypeId<QTFruit>(),
                                scriptedFruitObject);

 QScriptValue qsMetaObject =
        engine.newQMetaObject(fruit.metaObject());
 engine.globalObject().setProperty("eLedState",
                                       qsMetaObject);

int t = engine.evaluate("eLedState.On").toInteger();

engine.evaluate("fruit.fromJScript(1)");
engine.evaluate("fruit.fromJScript(eLedState.On)");

engine.evaluate("fruit.fromJScript(eLedState.TriState)");

//Create the ctor funtion
QScriptValue qsFruitCtor =
        engine.newFunction(QTFruitConstructor,
                                scriptedFruitObject);
//Expose ctor to javascript
 engine.globalObject().setProperty("QTFruit", qsFruitCtor);

 //Create the QTFruit object
engine.evaluate("var res = new QTFruit()");
engine.evaluate("res.fromJScript(eLedState.TriState)");


class QTFruit : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum eLedState { Off, On , TriState};
    Q_ENUMS( eLedState )    
    QTFruit();
    ~QTFruit();
     QTFruit( const QTFruit & other );

    //QTFruit(const QTFruit& other);

public slots:
    void fromJScript(eLedState state);
     //void on_inputSpinBox1_valueChanged(int value);
     //void on_buttonClicked();
//   void fromJScript();
//private:

};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QTFruit*)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QTFruit)

QScriptValue QTFruitConstructor(QScriptContext * /* context */,
                            QScriptEngine *interpreter);
```

Comment: And the cpp:QScriptValue QTFruitConstructor(QScriptContext * /* context */,
                                QScriptEngine *interpreter)
{
 //return interpreter->toScriptValue(new QTFruit());
 //or
 return interpreter->toScriptValue(QTFruit()); //but then you need the public copy contructor 
}

QTFruit::QTFruit( const QTFruit & other )
: QObject()
{
} 

QTFruit::~QTFruit()
{
}

QTFruit::QTFruit()
{
}

void QTFruit::fromJScript(eLedState state)
{
 int t = 0;
}

Answer (score -1):

And the cpp:

```
QScriptValue QTFruitConstructor(QScriptContext * /* context */,
                            QScriptEngine *interpreter)
{
    //return interpreter->toScriptValue(new QTFruit());
    //or
    return interpreter->toScriptValue(QTFruit()); //but then you need the public copy contructor 
}

 QTFruit::QTFruit( const QTFruit & other )
 : QObject()
{
} 

QTFruit::~QTFruit()
{
}

QTFruit::QTFruit()
{
}

void QTFruit::fromJScript(eLedState state)
{
    int t = 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want to add something to your previous answer you can edit it. While you're at it you might also want to add some explanation to your code.