# Q_OBJECT "copying" - copy all properties instead

Tags: qt, properties

As we all know, `Q_OBJECT`s are instances and are not copyable.

Is there any kind of syntactic sugar to copy all static and dynamic properties of an arbitrary `QObject` derived class?

It seems such a nobrainer, but I can't find any reference to such - obviously implementing one myself should be quite trivial - loop over `metaObject()`, loop over `dynamicPropertyNames()`, set accordingly.

Comment: Over how many `metaObject()`s do you want to loop? I think that the meta object of a subclass will tell you *all* (including inherited) meta properties of this object / class. This is why we actually need the offset methods of QMetaObject if we want the "additional" properties only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement a copy helper class as follows.

```
/** Enable QObjects to be explicitly copyable by copying property values. */
template<class T>
class QObjectCopyHelper<T>
{
protected:
    explicit QObjectCopyHelper(T *client) : m_client(client) {}

public:
    T *clone(QObject *parent = 0) {
        T *copy = new T(parent);

        // loop over and copy properties from m_client to copy
        // (both from T::staticMetaObject and dynamic ones)

        return copy;
    }

private:
    T *m_client; // <-- I think we need this, but I might be wrong
};
```

Then you can use this in any QObject subclass with very low work needed to be done:

```
class MyClass : public QObject, public QObjectCopyHelper<MyClass>
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
};
```

However, this still needs `clone()` to be called (the ugly "Java-style"). So we can additionally define a copy constructor just calling `clone()` and you also might think of a `assign()` method called within the assignment operator.

Please note that this really copies the properties only! There are a lot of other things being tracked in QObject, like the current connections. They explicitly forbid copying QObjects because it would be very difficult to define rules on how this should be done, and these rules would be the correct ones for some use cases only, while in others you want other rules...

Comment: Yeah, that's roughly what I ended up doing. However, I would guess having 2-3 different QObjectCopyStaticPropertiesHelper, QObjectCopyConnectionsHelper, etc.. would allow us to use arbitrary combination of rules.

Comment: @qdot Oh yeah, very nice idea! One last word about the "m_client" pointer I needed in my code: An alternative would be to call `clone(this)` instead of `clone()` and use the provided pointer as the source object. This avoids another member and thus reduces the memory overhead. I think we can't drop the pointer at all, because we can't cast `this` from within the helper class towards `T*`. But I might be wrong here and would be happy if I'm corrected by someone knowing it better! ;)

Answer (score 2):

A solution is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956335/subclass-of-qobject-qregistermetatype-and-the-private-copy-constructor), where they take the loop-over-the-properties approach. There seems to be no "syntactic sugar" here.