# I can't take QObject information from an object created as a subclass of QObject using reflection

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have to create an instance of an object (subclass of `QObject`) using reflection.

Let's suppose this object is `MyQObject` and have declared the following properties using the `Q_PROPERTY` macro: `MyQObject1* p1`, `MyQObject2* p2`, `MyQObject3* p3`, ...

Let's say I have this function to do that:

```
    QObject* Manager::createInstanceOf(const QMetaObject* c, QList<const char*> paramsNames, QList<QObject*> oparams) {
    QObject* instance = (QObject*) c->newInstance();

        for(int i = 0; i < paramsNames.length(); i++) {
            QVariant variant = QVariant::fromValue(oparams[i]);
            instance->setProperty(paramsNames[i], variant);
        }
    return instance;
   }
```

where:

`c` is the `QMetaObject*` associated with `MyQObject`.

`paramsNames` is a `QList<const char*>` containing the names of the properties declared in the object's class definition through the `Q_PROPERTY` macro. In this example, `QList` contains: `"MyQObject1"`, `"MyQObject2"`, `"MyQObject3"`, ...

`oparams` is a `QList<QObject*>` containing the properties of the object already instantiated. None of them is a `QObject` per se, but a subclass of `QObject`, and might not be all the same. In this example, a `QList` containing a instance for `MyQObject1`, `MyQObject2`, `MyQObject3`...

My problem is that although the instance of `MyQObject` is created and the types were registered using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro and `qRegisterMetaType`, I can't access to any of the properties' methods associated with `QObject` without getting segfault. In few words, I can't do:

```
myQObjectInstance->property("p1").value<MyQObject1*>()->metaObject();
```

but I can access without problem other methods of the properties that are not from `QObject`. For example:

```
myQObjectInstance->property("p1").value<MyQObject1*>()->toString();
```

I realized that if I cast the property before doing the `setProperty`, my problem can be solved partially:

```
QVariant::fromValue((MyQObject1*) oparams[0]);
```

It seems to be that if the property is not set as the specific subclass of `QObject` as it was created, but casted as its superclass (when inserted in `oparams` `QList` they are automatically casted), is what causes the problem.

Due to the different types of the properties (`MyQObject1`, `MyQObject2`, `MyQObject3`,...) I can't cast one by one because I don't know this information at compile time.

So, any ideas?

I will really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: I would check to see if value<MyQObject*>() is returning NULL.  If so, that would expelling the segfault (although it wouldn't explain why the method is returning NULL)

Comment: No, it's not returning NULL. Actually, value<MyQObject1*> is returning the instantiated object, but I can only access those methods that are not from the QObject superclass. In my example, I can access to toString() which is a method from MyQObject1, but when I access to metaObject() or another method from QObject, I get segfault. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Useful reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956335/subclass-of-qobject-qregistermetatype-and-the-private-copy-constructor